# Windows Events: How to interpret Failure Code

Tags: windows, windows-event-log

I am new to Windows Logs.

When looking at events in the events viewer the failure status and sub status show cryptic values like 0xC000006D and 0xC0000064. Besides doing a google search is there any place where I can look up for these and interpret their value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of resources for error code lookup can be found at Microsoft Docs  here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes

It includes

- System (OS) error codes
- Windows Updates error code
- Windows activation error codes
- Blue Screen of Death (BSOD) error codes
- ... and others

Also, take a look at [Microsoft Error Lookup Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-code-lookup-tool)

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [SYSTEM32](https://system32.eventsentry.com), much better interface plus you have event descriptions there too along with error code lookups.